# How to detect refresh, tab closing, webrowser closing. Vaadin 6, Java 8, Sping, Must work on Firefox

Tags: java, spring, firefox, vaadin

Hi How to detect refresh, tab closing, webrowser closing in Firefox? Im using Java 8, Spring na Vaadin 6 libraries for now. Javscript solution mentioned many times on this portal dont work in my case.

Regards

Comment: A refresh should be noticable since it's a new request to your webapp. But you won't be able to distinguish if it's an actual refresh or some other request with the same url. You cannot detect the other two events unless the browser specifically tells you about it, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

There cannot be any guarantee about definitely detecting closing a tab or the browser since they might happen while the user is offline. This means that you shouldn't design your application in a way that relies on that. What you can rely on is that the session will be expired if there is no activity from the user in a given duration.

You can detect refreshes by enabling the preserve on refresh feature and overriding the `refresh` method in your `UI` class since it will be run by the framework when a refresh occurs.